# 2021: Recommended way to capture user input & workflow (form? powerapp? word/excel doc?)

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, power-automate, word, powerapp

SharePoint Cloud... what is the current/modern recommended method to replace an old school paper form that a reviewer adds/edits content and then an approver does a final approve?

So:

- Capture user input to a number of questions/request
- Send that data to a person to review **AND** allow that person to add or edit content of the request
- Send everything to an approver
- Easily view the full contents

Pulling my hair out over a scenario that should be solved out of the box but yet again requires some complicated solution.

- Forms (for Excel) aren't great because a reviewer can't modify prior to approval, audit trail not so great, etc.
- Word/Excel Docs have numerous issues because SharePoint issues (wd/xl online can't show SharePoint field drop down choices, flow nightmares around check-in resulting in overly complex flow, etc.)
- PowerApp has high learning curve and looks overly complex (and wasted effort if need to migrate back to G Suite - client not 100% committed to o365 suite long-term)

I think I can create what I need with a combination of all these tools (and maybe SharePoint Lists to store data, etc.) but each solution appears to have a super high cost and drawbacks. If there's a consensus on the best way, then I'll invest the time.

Help! Thanks!